# Django: Order by two fields (one nullable)

Tags: python, django, sorting

i have the following model

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

Sample data:

```
[{'id': 1}, {'id': 2, 'parent': 1}, {'id': 3, 'parent': 1}, {'id': 4}, {'id': 5, 'parent': 1}, {'id': 6, 'parent': 3}, {'id': 7, 'parent': 4}, {'id': 8, 'parent': 3}, {'id': 9, 'parent': 1}]
```

I would like to order each parent node with all it's children using the django ORM, the expected output for the sample data would be something like this:

```
1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 5, 4, 7, 9
```

for each parent show its children after them. Any ideas on how this could be done?

I was thinking that maybe with some aggregated field and sorting by it, but i'm a bit stuck on this one.

Comment: If you plan on creating a complex tree structure, it might be worth to have a look at `django-mptt` or `django-treebeard`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Risadinha for your comment, finally i did the following:

Override my model save method to store the matherialized_path

```
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
        update_fields=None):
        super(Position, self).save(force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update, using=using,
                               update_fields=update_fields)

        self.materialized_path = self.get_materialized_path()

        return super(Position, self).save(force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update, using=using,
                                      update_fields=update_fields)

    def get_materialized_path(self):
        parent = self.parent
        materialized_path = [str(self.id)]

        while (parent is not None) and parent.id != self.id:
            materialized_path.insert(0, str(parent.id))
            parent = parent.parent

        return '.'.join(materialized_path)
```

Then, use the generated field to order_by it's values